# Linq without foreach?

Tags: c#, linq

```
              string popUpHTML="";

                var xx = from Temp in TemplateList
                                where
                                (
                                Temp.TitleID == titleID
                                )
                                select Temp.HTML;

                foreach (var s in xx)
                {
                    popUpHTML =  s.ToString();
                }
```

The code above is working. The executed linq is supposed to return only one value. Is there any way I can get the result of the above LINQ without a foreach loop. (Sorry I am new to LINQ).

Update: titleID is a unique key in the database, hence only one result is expected.

Comment: When you say return only one value, do you mean the first value or the last? Because the code you posted sets popUpHTML to the last value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now your query returns an `IEnumerable`, instead use `FirstOrDefault()` (or `Single()` if you are absolutely sure that there always will be *exactly* one result):

```
 var popUpHTML = (from Temp in TemplateList
                  where Temp.TitleID == titleID
                  select Temp.HTML).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: a very simple and straight forward answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var popUpHTML = TemplateList.Where(temp => temp.TitleID == titleID)
                            .Select(temp => temp.HTML)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
```

`popUpHtml` is `null` if there doesn't exist an item with the provided ID.

Comment: This would select a `Template` item but not its `HTML` property which is what OP wants

Answer (score 2):

```
string popUpHTML = 
    (
     from Temp in TemplateList 
     where ( Temp.TitleID == titleID ) 
     select Temp.HTML
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var xx = (from Temp in TemplateList
                where
                (
                Temp.TitleID == titleID
                )
                select Temp.HTML).Take(1);
```

Comment: You'd still have to call FirstOrDefault here (or First or Single).

Answer (score 0):

```
var popUpHTML = TemplateList.FirstOrDefault(Temp => Temp.TitleID == titleID);
```